# Hand cursor does not appear over radio buttons on flag dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flag-dialog

The arrow cursor does not change into the hand cursor when it moves over the radio buttons of the "I am flagging to report this question as..." or the "I am flagging to report this answer as..." dialog that first appears after clicking "flag" under a question or answer:

[image]

On clicking the radio button and moving to the next dialog, the hand cursor behaves as expected, though this has not been tested exhaustively (due to a fear of actually flagging something by mistake).

Tested on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/), and [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

This behaviour also occurs after clicking "flag" from the "Actions" panel of the Triage queue on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Yeah for some odd reason the radio button in the flag dialog is missing the `s-radio` class, which defines, among other things, the mouse cursor that should appear when hovering over it.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Yes, that sounds reasonable. The problem I first noticed was that (in dark mode) the radio button is white on the first dialog and black on the second and deeper dialogs. Those dialogs have the `s-radio` class, so I guess that when they fix the hand cursor then the colour should get fixed too.

Comment: That is correct, the class has more properties in it. :)

Comment: `<quibble>` I don't really understand why _any_ radio button wouldn't want `.s-radio` styling – so why doesn't Stacks just put that styling on `input[type="radio"]`? I get the whole "every style is a class" thing, but that's not how CSS is supposed to work, and things like this are why. `</quibble>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. I put in a pull request to add the missing `s-radio` class. Should be able to merge it after new years.

Comment: "after new years" might not be trivial to understand (e.g. my new year was back in September ;-)), you mean January 1st?

Comment: Yes, after the first business day of the year 2024 in the Gregorian calendar 